# Deserializing a class with a Queue<T> with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json, c#-4.0, queue, deserialization, json.net

I have a class that has a property of type Queue. When trying to deserialize the JSON, I get the following error:

> **Type specified in JSON** 'ConsoleApplication1.Task[], ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' **is not compatible with** 'System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[[ConsoleApplication1.Task, ConsoleApplication1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Path 'Tasks.$type', line 1, position 140.

I have included the sample application below and I am using Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.10.15407.

The reason I am using a Queue instead of List or Dictionary is because I must preserve insert order. I've also tried searching in the docs and other questions but haven't really found anything concrete. Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Message message = new Message
                {
                    MessageID = 1,
                    Tasks = new Queue<Task>()
                };
            message.Tasks.Enqueue(new Task{TaskId = 1, Message = "Test1", Parameters = "Param1"});
            message.Tasks.Enqueue(new Task{TaskId = 2, Message = "Test2", Parameters = "Param2"});

            byte[] bSerialized = SerializeJsonWithPrefix(message);
            Message deserializedMessage = DeserializeJson(bSerialized, typeof (Message));
        }

        public static byte[] SerializeJsonWithPrefix(Message item)
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jss.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, jss));
        }

        public static Message DeserializeJson(byte[] ueaData, Type concreteType)
        {
            JsonSerializerSettings jss = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            jss.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;

            // --- Error occurs here ---
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ueaData), concreteType, jss);
            return (Message)result;
        }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        public int MessageID { get; set; }
        public Queue<Task> Tasks { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Task
    {
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Parameters { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Version 5 solves your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I stick to `List<T>` and `Dictionary<string, T>` when using JSON.NET serialization, where T is some JSON-serializable type.  These correspond nicely to the JSON array and object types (see [json.org](http://json.org/)).

If you serialize a `List<T>` and then deserialize it, JSON.NET will of course maintain the ordering. I would advise just translating between your `Queue<T>` and a `List<T>` for serialization, rather than trying to add behavior for directly serializing the `Queue<T>`.